# Pronunciation of ‘a’ when the article is modified by an adverb

Tags: pronunciation

‘A’ means one. If ‘a’ is modified by an adverb, for example ‘only,’ in ‘only a star.’ Do I better say ‘a’ as the sound in ‘make,’ not as schwa sound?

Comment: It's normally pronounced schwa, even if it's modified by an adverb. If you want to stress the 'a' for whatever reason, then you can pronounce it as it is in 'make' (I can't imagine any scenario where you'd pronounce it that way). If you pronounced the 'a' in *only a star* with the vowel of 'make', I'd think you were referring to a star named A.

Comment: @Void. Thank youuuuuu

Comment: You might stress the indefinite article in a context like *That's only **a** star - it's not the specific star I'm looking for.*